# How to pass 64 bit float uniform to webgl shaders from wasm?

Tags: rust, webgl, webassembly, webgl2, web-sys

I'm currently attempting to interface with a webgl2 canvas from a WASM program using  `wasm_bindgen` and the `web_sys` crate. I am passing two vectors into my fragment shader as uniforms however I cant determine how to send them as double precision. It seems like `web_sys` only has methods for setting f32 values in uniforms.

My understanding is that the `WebGl2RenderingContext.uniform2v` method supports the javascript `Number` type which supports double precision floats but it seems there is no analogue in `web_sys`.

Still fairly new to WebGL and WASM so any insights as to what I'm missing or ideas for workarounds would be appreciated. Cheers!

The data being used for the uniforms is defined on a struct

```rs
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct CanvasData {
    // (snip)
    view_min: [f64; 2],
    view_max: [f64; 2],
}
```

And I'm setting the value of the uniforms with

```rs
// Set view region uniforms
let vmin = [self.view_min[0] as f32, self.view_min[1] as f32];
let vmax = [self.view_max[0] as f32, self.view_max[1] as f32];
// ^ If possible I don't want to cast these to f32 ^
gl_context
  .uniform2fv_with_f32_array(Some(&view_min_uniform_location), &vmin);
gl_context
  .uniform2fv_with_f32_array(Some(&view_max_uniform_location), &vmax);
```

The relevant part of the fragment shader is

```c
#version 300 es

precision highp float;

uniform highp vec2 uViewMin;
uniform highp vec2 uViewMax;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  // (snip)

  vec2 z = vec2(mix(uViewMin.x, uViewMax.x, 1.0 - uv.x), mix(uViewMin.y, uViewMax.y, uv.y));

  // (snip)
}
```

Comment: *"uniform2v method supports the javascript Number"* yes but it still casts to 32bit single precision float as glsl  es 3.0 doesn't have a double precision floating point type. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74790150/calculations-that-work-in-js-dont-work-in-glsl/74793219#74793219

Comment: @LJᛃ cheers, I had a feeling that might be the case. Appreciate the link 